# Entity Framework, map 2 X 1 to 1 relationships to the same model

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have 2 Entity Framework models, the first is an Employee model and the second is a Lead model. There are 2 employees dealing with each new generated lead. The first does the cold calling, the second follows up. The primary key for the Employee model is EmployeeId and the Lead model I want to have two foreign keys something along the lines of EmployeeId1 and EmplyeeId2 both tied in a 1 to 1 relationships with the Employee model

```
public class Lead
{
   [Key]
   public int LeadId { get; set; }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   //foreign key to EmployeeId in Employee model
   public int EmplyeeId2 { get; set; }

   //second foreign Key to EmployeeId in Employee model
   public int EmplyeeId1 { get; set; }

   public virtual Employee Employee {get; set;}
}
```

Any idea on the best way to do this so that i can access the linked properties in Linq using something like Lead.Employee.EmployeeName?

Comment: If you want 1:1 relation ship what would you expect 'Lead.Employee.EmployeeName' to return? The first or the second employee? If you want to do it this way you should add two navigation properties not just have a single 'Employee'. You should then associate these two new navigation properties with their respective foreign keys. You can configure this using attributes, convention or fluent api

Comment: That is the part I wasn't sure of, how to differentiate between the 2 linked Employees. Can you perhaps provide and example of how i can do it using Attributes or Fluent API as i am fairly new to Entity Framework and haven't been able to find any examples online.

Comment: See answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick :)

```
public class Lead {
    [Key]
    public int LeadId { get; set; }

    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    public string LastName { get; set; }

    //foreign key to EmployeeId in Employee model
    public int EmplyeeId2 { get; set; }

    //second foreign Key to EmployeeId in Employee model
    public int EmplyeeId1 { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("EmplyeeId1")]
    public virtual Employee Employee1 {get; set;}

    [ForeignKey("EmplyeeId2")]
    public virtual Employee Employee2 {get; set;}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a scenario when you have a class Employee and two classes that inherit from this class. But I don't think is a good idea to name this classes Employee1 and Employee2, their can have name related with some characteristics of this employees like Manager and Supervisor.

Class Employee

```
public class Employee 
{
 public string FName {get; set;}
 public string LName{ get; set;}
 // other properties
 }
```

Class Manager:

```
public class Manager: Employee 
{
 public int ManagerId {get; set;}

 public int LeadId{ get; set;}
 public virtual Lead Lead{ get; set;}
 // other properties
 }
```

Class Supervisor:

```
public class Supervisor: Employee 
{
 public int SupervisorId {get; set;}
 public virtual Lead Lead{ get; set;}
 public int LeadId{ get; set;}
 // other properties
 }
```

Class Lead:

```
 public class Lead
{
   [Key]
   public int LeadId { get; set; }

   public string FirstName { get; set; }

   public string LastName { get; set; }

   //foreign key to EmployeeId in Employee model
   public int SupervisorId { get; set; }

   //second foreign Key to EmployeeId in Employee model
   public int ManagerId { get; set; }

   public virtual Manager Manager{ get; set;} 
   public virtual Supervisor Supervisor {get; set;}
}
```

Foregn Key with fluent api:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Lead>()
            .HasOne(p => p.Manager)
            .WithOne(i => i.Lead)
            .HasForeignKey<Manager>(b => new {b.ManagerId, b.SupervisorId});
```

Comment: Thanks, this is really an elegant solution and i am going to bookmark it for future use. I decided to go with the answer from @i regular though as it requires the least code and i haven't been given much time to finish this project.

Comment: You choose the answer that you want but why the downvote?

Comment: I never down voted your answer at all. I actually up voted it for how good it was. I don't see any down votes for your answer either.

Comment: It is not recommended to name your entities with the same name adding just a number. Check this tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/inheritance?view=aspnetcore-2.0 . And even foreign keys used with attributes is not the recommended away to work with.